# Network tools not working with a 3G connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, 3g

Some of my network tools stopped working after I switched to a 3G connection from a DSL one. Cain and Abel's sniffer, Metasploit, even the NMAP scanner.

I'm using Windows 7. The 3G device in question is the Huawei E180.

Here's the error I get when running NMAP

> WARNING: Using raw sockets because ppp2 is not an ethernet device. This probably won't work on Windows.
>
> pcap_open_live(ppp2, 100, 0, 2) FAILED. Reported error: Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20).  Will wait 5 seconds then retry.
>
> pcap_open_live(ppp2, 100, 0, 2) FAILED. Reported error: Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20).  Will wait 25 seconds then retry.
>
> Call to pcap_open_live(ppp2, 100, 0, 2) failed three times. Reported error: Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20)

Metasploit's refused connection to my websites too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"""WINDOWS: Nmap only supports ethernet interfaces on Windows for most operations because Microsoft disabled raw sockets as of Windows XP SP2. Depending on the reason for this error, it is possible that the --unprivileged command-line argument will help."""

Since I am having the same issue as you, I got this answer from another forum for you, our best bet seems ubuntu, though win7 is just so good

Comment: Been a while since I asked that question. Thank you for answering it. I don't need it anymore but I hope it helps someone else out.